# How do you write a Rails model method to return a list of its associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

What I'm trying to do is write a method that will return all of this model's outing_locations, to which it has a has_many relationship.

```
class Outing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :end_time, :start_time, :title, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :outing_locations
  has_many :outing_guests
  has_one :time_range, :foreign_key => "element_id", :conditions => { :element_type => "outing" }

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :start_time, :presence => true # regex
  validates :end_time, :presence => true # regex

  def host_name
    return User.find(self.user_id).full_name
  end


end
```

I'm trying to get this block in particular to work.

There's another model called OutingInvite, which contains the id of a particular Outing. I need to use that to grab the proper Outing and then pull said Outing's associated outing locations.

Here's a rough sample:

```
<%@outing_invites.each do |invite|%>
 ...
    <% @party = Outing.where(:id => invite.outing_id) %>
    <% @party.outing_locations.each do |location| %>
```

And then have it output each location.

However, it's saying the method 'outing_locations' does not exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a model's associated models by typing `model_instance.associated_model_name.` So in your example, an `outing` has_many `outing_locations`. After you have an instance of an `outing`,  say by using `@o = Outing.find(1)`, you can then use `o.outing_locations` to see the `outing_locations` associated with that specific `outing.`

See [this example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) from the Ruby on Rails Guide.

**EDIT**

The reasons you're getting the `method 'outing_locations' does not exist` error is because `Outing.where(:id => invite.outing_id)` returns an array, and there is no `outing_locations` method for arrays. You'll need to either get the specific instance (like with `Outing.find(invite.outing_id`) or use a specific index in that array. I recommend using `Outing.find(invite.outing_id)` since (I'm assuming) each of your Outing's has a unique id.

Comment: That's what I thought, too.
I've added more code to illustrate what exactly I'm trying to do, and the problems I'm having...

Comment: That totally did it! Thank you!